# Null Value for datagridview cell vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

How to get for null value in datagridview i did this in the cell validation event but it dosent seem to work. I want the user to add a new row and someone force him to give an ID or delete the row. What am i doing wrong. This is not a how to do question. This is a what is wrong Question. So right now it detects null but once i corrected the cell it still dosent allow me to get out of the row.

```
          If DataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        If IsDBNull(DataGrid.CurrentCell.Value) Then
            Msgbox("Cannot be Null")
              e.cancel = true
        ElseIf Not IsDBNull(DataGrid.CurrentCell.Value) Then
              e.cancel = False

        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i tried this and it works for me . it simply uses e.formatedvalue. Current Cell Value is the cell value before and after edit while formatedvalue is what is being typed it . i guess i understand now so here is the coding

```
              If grdDataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If e.FormattedValue = "" Or IsDBNull(e.FormattedValue) Then
            MsgBox("Cannot be Null")
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub

        End If
    End If
```

They are also different ways like adjusting your column properties to not allowed null but since the column properties inherit from the database i decided to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be works ...

```
If DataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    If IsDBNull(DataGrid.CurrentCell.Value) Then
          Msgbox("Cannot be Null")
          e.cancel = true
          exit sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Still the same after i corrected the cell by adding the value i still cant leave the row due to e.cancel. Thats why i added he elseif. But am i correct to place it at cell validation?

Comment: @shaikibrahim .. did you put this in cellvalidating event ?

Comment: Is that the only code in cellvalidating or there is some other code below ?

Comment: they are more codes below but those are for integers those work just fine . This code does tell me that the value is null but it only validate once. I tried a for loop it works but the msgbox keep popping out again and again

Answer (score 0):

Another way around this would be to explicitly set the default null value for the new datagrid cell to the value you are checking for. For instance,set the null= to an empty string if you are pulling string values.  You can use the properties palette to set this.

Comment: While this could be a valid answer, you might want to show the code for what you are attempting to explain.